# Compiling and using Bootstrap LESS files

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

I would like to use Bootstrap CSS for my Django/Dojo project. I have downloaded an archive with files and extracted all LESS into separate folder.

The problem is that during LESS-compilation I've got errors - most of the bootstrap LESS files use variables from `variables.less`, however `import` statements are not specified.

Is there any way to handle this, or does one have to manually add `import "variables.less";' to each file?

Comment: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/bootstrap.less - all @imports are in the bootstrap.less

Comment: @makshh Thank you, that makes sense. Fixed the problem. If you add the answer - I can mark it as solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap uses `bootstrap.less` file to import other `*.less` Bootstrap files. You have to compile `bootstrap.less`, when you see the error you are probably trying to compile other `.less` files which don't have @import rules at all.

bootstrap.less:

```
/*!
 * Bootstrap v3.3.5 (http://getbootstrap.com)
 * Copyright 2011-2015 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */

// Core variables and mixins
@import "variables.less";
@import "mixins.less";

// Reset and dependencies
@import "normalize.less";
@import "print.less";
@import "glyphicons.less";

// Core CSS
@import "scaffolding.less";
@import "type.less";
@import "code.less";
@import "grid.less";
@import "tables.less";
@import "forms.less";
@import "buttons.less";

// Components
@import "component-animations.less";
@import "dropdowns.less";
@import "button-groups.less";
@import "input-groups.less";
@import "navs.less";
@import "navbar.less";
@import "breadcrumbs.less";
@import "pagination.less";
@import "pager.less";
@import "labels.less";
@import "badges.less";
@import "jumbotron.less";
@import "thumbnails.less";
@import "alerts.less";
@import "progress-bars.less";
@import "media.less";
@import "list-group.less";
@import "panels.less";
@import "responsive-embed.less";
@import "wells.less";
@import "close.less";

// Components w/ JavaScript
@import "modals.less";
@import "tooltip.less";
@import "popovers.less";
@import "carousel.less";

// Utility classes
@import "utilities.less";
@import "responsive-utilities.less";
```